# Find folders pinned to Quick Access when saving/loading in programs such as CutePDF an Autocad (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, autocad, cutepdf, windows-10-quick-access

I use Windows 10, and I have a lot of folders pinned to Quick Access in the File Explorer. Quick Access is a useful tool and it saves me a lot of time when going through my files and folders.

However, the Quick Access tool is not available when saving files within certain programs (e.g. CutePDF, Autocad etc.), or at least I haven't been able to find it there. Loading/saving in such programs is therefore a bit more cumbersome than what I would like.

My solution was to create a folder on my desktop with a copy/shortcut to my pinned Quick Access folders, but so far I haven't managed to do this.

Any ideas how to do this? Or, if possible, how I could find the Quick Access folders when saving in CutePDF, Autocad and other programs where the Quick Access is not showing?

**EDIT:**

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNXxe.png) from Autocad. In file explorer in windows, the Quick Access folders are found on the top of the left window, but in Autocad (and other programs) I can't find them.

I could of course create a new folder with "normal" shortcuts to each folder pinned to Quick Access, but that would create a bit extra work each time I add or remove a folder to Quick Access. Pinning to Quick Access is very fast and easy, making a new short cut and copying it to the right folder is not much work, but I would like to avoid the double work if if possible :)

Comment: Not familiar with the software you mentioned. Do they not use the common dialogs? Can you take a screenshot of the dialogs, post to an image site, and edit your post with a link to the image(s)?

Comment: What difficulty are you having with creating a folder filled with 'normal' shortcuts?

Comment: @KeithMiller, I have updated the post now :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to use a third-party tool to add that functionality.

Here are some ideas:

- [ClipAngel](https://sourceforge.net/projects/clip-angel/)
  is an open-source clipboard extender that has a favorite list.
  Defining these folders as favorite will make them easily accessible in every
  program of any kind.
- [FileBox eXtender](https://www.techsupportalert.com/content/filebox-extender.htm-1)
  extends the open and save dialogs. Free and open source.
- [FlashFolder](https://www.techsupportalert.com/content/flashfolder.htm-0)
  also extends the open and save dialogs. Free and open source.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I have tried to check out the tools.
 - In the tool descriptions, it says that Filebox extender and FlashFolder does not work on newer versions of Windows.
 - I cant see that ClipAngel does what I am asking for, but I could be mistaking.

Comment: I agree that extensions are not a long-term solution, since they may be disabled by changes in Windows. I believe that using a third-party clipboard extender that keeps an easily-accessed folder-paths list is the most resistant solution. ClipAngel  is just the one I'm using now, but there are [many others](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-clipboard-replacement-utility.htm).